# Iron IO - Laravel queue management

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using IronIO and Laravel 4.2 to post videos up to Vimeo.

My process is

1. User Uploads Video
2. Queue Manager Starts and Uploads Video In Background
3. The Application then posts to Social Media

I have completed parts 1 & 2, But part 3 is proving a little tricky and am not sure why.

My code for the Queue Return is as follows :

```
Event::listen('file.encode', function($data)
{
    //create a new job
    $j = new Job();
    $j->status = 'queued';
    $j->save();
    $data['id'] = $j->id;

    Queue::push(function($job) use ($data)
    {
        // Set a NEW Path...
        $filePath = getcwd() .'/'. $data['post_media_path'];

        // Now Process The Vimeo Stuff....
        $upload = Vimeo::upload($filePath, false);
        $video_data = Vimeo::request($upload);

        if($video_data['status'] == 200)
        {
            $clip_id = str_replace(array("/", "videos"), "", $video_data['body']['uri']);

            // Now Save The Video Data...
            $post_media = PostMedia::find($data['post_media_id']);
            $post_media->vimeo_clip_id = $clip_id;
            $post_media->post_source = 'vimeo';
            $post_media->save();

            $ejob = Job::find($data['id']); // Find the job in database
            $ejob->status = 'finished'; //Set job status to finished
            $ejob->save();

            // Now Send To Videos Controller (To Deal With Social Media Posting - If User has it setup)...
            return Redirect::to('admin/post-social-media/'.$clip_id);
        }
    });

});
```

It is worth saying that if I run the route :

> admin/post-social-media/1176758

The data all gets posted to Social Media, So it works. But I'm having a nightmare debugging the route code. Am I doing something wrong in terms of a redirect or similar?

Thank You

Comment: Your job will be executed on the Queue, in the background. Returning a redirect response will have no use, because this process is running "somewhere else" (IronIO), eg you have no access to it anymore as a client.

Comment: Thanks @Luceos any suggestions on how I can get that to run then? I don't get the Vimeo ID back till after the queue manager is run,,

Comment: Yes so either make the page wait (poll) for the task to be ready or notify the user once it's done.